# number of arguments for a function in pthread

Tags: c, pthreads

In hello world example of pthread it is stated:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void * print_hello(void *arg)
{
  printf("Hello world!\n");
  return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  pthread_t thr;
  if(pthread_create(&thr, NULL, &print_hello, NULL))
  {
    printf("Could not create thread\n");
    return -1;
  }

  if(pthread_join(thr, NULL))
  {
    printf("Could not join thread\n");
    return -1;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

As you can see `print_hello` in `pthread_create()` has no argument, however in the definition, it looks like `void * print_hello(void *arg)`

What does that mean?

Now assume I have this implementation

```
void * print_hello(int a, void *);
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  pthread_t thr;
  int a = 10;
  if(pthread_create(&thr, NULL, &print_hello(a), NULL))
  {
    printf("Could not create thread\n");
    return -1;
  }
  ....
  return 0;
}
void * print_hello(int a, void *arg)
{
  printf("Hello world and %d!\n", a);
  return NULL;
}
```

Now I get this error:

```
too few arguments to function print_hello
```

So how can I fix that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`pthread` passes one argument of type `void *` to thread function, So you can pass a pointer to any type of data that you want as fourth argument of `pthread_create` function, look at the example below that fixes your code.

```
void * print_hello(void *);
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    pthread_t thr;
    int a = 10;
    if(pthread_create(&thr, NULL, &print_hello, (void *)&a))
    {
        printf("Could not create thread\n");
        return -1;
    }
    ....
    return 0;
}

void * print_hello(void *arg)
{
    int a = (int)*arg;
    printf("Hello world and %d!\n", a);
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: Yes that is fine. Thanks. Does that mean only one argument can be passed? In another word, if I want to pass `a` and `b`, then `...(void *)&a, (void *)&b...` is correct?

Comment: No you can't pass two integers in this way, but for example you can pass them in form of an integer array with size 2, eg: `int a[2] = {10, 20};` and then pass `(void *)a` as fourth argument of `pthread_create`.

Comment: @mahmood: Yes, only one. If you want to pass more than one thing, make a struct or a class.  Also, this code has a race condition (that, in practice, won't cause any trouble in this specific instance) since it passes the address of a local variable in one thread to another.  If the function were to return before the thread tried to access the data, you'd get undefined results, up to and including garbage data or segmentation violations.  Since the function in question is main, returning from it will kill the program so in this specific case it's meaningless.