# How can I use multiple arguments when calling a method with a pthread?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I have a problem with my C program, because I don't really know, how to use the pthread_create method with a function that has multiple arguments.
My code shall find primes in an array. Therefor I am forced to use `n` threads, each looking in one part of the array.
Here is what my code looks like:

```
for (int i = 0; i< n - 1; i++) {
        pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, checkArrayPart,(size*i, size*(i+1),values));
    }

pthread_create(&threads[n-1], NULL, checkArrayPart,(size*i, size*(i+1),values)));
```

the method `checkArrayPart` looks like this:

```
 int checkArrayPart(int begin, int end, int arr[]){
     int localCounter = 0;
     for (int i = begin; i <= end; i++) {
        if (isPrime(arr[i])) {
            localCounter++;
        }
    }
    return localCounter;
 }
```

I tried to compile my code and it is not working. I think the problem is in the part where I give the new thread the arguments for the method it shall run. So, is there a way to use multiple arguments in a method given to a pthread?

I appreciate any help. Thank you... :)

Comment: The value passed for `end` will be less than the value passed for `begin`. So the loop will not iterate.

Comment: thx, I corrected it

Comment: Yes but was that the mistake, or a posting error? Please copy/paste code. Has your code got `-1` or `+1`? It's now unclear what you are asking.

Comment: just a posting error. I will use copy/paste in the future, sorry... So that means my code is still not working

Comment: You could pass a struct.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19917211/create-pthread-with-the-function-of-multiple-arguments Check the second answer. It will give you an idea

Answer (score 1):

> So, is there a way to use multiple arguments in a method given to a pthread?

Yes: you have to wrap multiple arguments in a struct:

```
struct Args {
  int begin, end;
  int *arr;
};

void *call_checkArrayPart(void *p) {
  struct Args *args = (struct Args *) p;
  int rc = checkArrayPart(args->begin, args->end, args->arr);
  return (void *) rc;
}
```

At creation time, you need to pack your args into this struct:

```
struct Args args[n];
for (int i = 0; i< n - 1; i++) {
  struct Args *arg = &args[i];
  arg->begin = size * i;
  args->end = args->begin + size;
  args->arr = values;
  pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, call_checkArrayPart, arg);
}
```

Comment: First of all: Thanks a lot... :) I have one understanding issue. What is the line `struct Args *args = (struct Args *);` for? I am really new to C and I don't understand, what this line is going to do.

Comment: @Mr.Moose Sorry, it's a typo. Actually two typos. Fixed.